# Redirecionar usuário através de outra variável, mantendo o meu background - PHP

Tags: php

boa tarde!

É possível eu colocar um `href` para redirecionar á outra página dentro de uma variável?

Tenho uma simples listagem aonde exibo o nome, e do lado tenho um `button` que redireciona para uma página de edição, **gostaria de colocar essa mesma função do `button`, aonde eu exibo o nome, é possível?**

Meu código aonde exibo o nome: `echo" <td>{$cont['nome']}</td>";`

Meu button:

```
echo "
<td> 
<a href='edit_personal.php?id=".$cont['id']."&nome=".$cont['nome']." target='new_blank'></a> 
</td>";
```

Eu já tentei, porém não funcionou...

Comment: Faltou fechar as aspas simples do atributo `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O título da sua pergunta é um pouco confuso, mas se eu entendi bem o seu problema é apenas com concatenação.

As aspas duplas dizem ao **PHP** para iniciar a interpolação e isso gasta mais recurso. O ideal seria utilizar a aspa única quando não é utilizado a interpolação.

```
// Exemplo utilizando concatenação
echo '<td><a href="edit_personal.php?id=' . $cont['id'] . '&nome=' . $cont['nome'] . '" target="new_blank">' . $cont['nome'] . '</a></td>';

// Exemplo utilizando interpolação
echo "<td><a href='edit_personal.php?id={$cont['id']}&nome={$cont['nome']}' target='new_blank'>{$cont['nome']}</a></td>";
```

Comment: Testou? Deu algum erro?

Comment: Estou tentando, mas não foi, **acho que é algum erro meu**... `<td style='background-color:$cor'><a href='edit_personal.php?id='.$cont['id'].'&nome='.$cont['nome']. '' target='new_blank'><b>'.$cont['nome'].'</b></a></td>";` acabei esquecendo de colocar umas coisinhas no post... (ja tem um echo em cima)

Comment: Está com alguns erros de concatenação, por que você não copiou e colou o código que eu coloquei? Tá totalmente diferente.

Comment: Eu fiz, só acrescentei o background na td e tirei o echo por que tinha em cima

Comment: Pois é, nessa pequena mudança que você fez, você acabou esquecendo de substituir as aspas duplas pela simples.

Substitui o `echo "` por `echo  '` e usa o código da resposta.

Comment: Dessa maneira funcionou, porém, o meu `style='background-color:$cor'` NÃO está funcionando...`echo ' <td style="background-color:$cor"><a href="edit_relatorio.php?codigo_relatorio='.$cont['codigo_relatorio'].'&paciente='.$cont['paciente']. '" target="new_blank">
               <b>'.$cont['paciente'].'</b></a></td>';`

Comment: Tenta o seguinte: `<td style="background-color:' . $cor . ' ">`.
Atualiza sua pergunta com esse trecho da cor que eu atualizo a resposta para ficar com o código completo para você.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada!